# spring integration dynamic sql in query property

Tags: spring-integration

How can I inject a sql to query property in int-jdbc:outbound-gateway?

Background:
I receive an amqp message with a where clause to query a table and do some logic. Where clause could be anything like state in ('ca','ma) or zipcode = '01760'
Is there an example on using int-jdbc:outbound-gateway passing a query that can change based on the received message?

For example:
we receive amqp message: 
1: {"whereClause":"State in ('ca','ma')"}
2: {"whereClause":"id = 1"}

How can I inject to query prop in int-jdbc:outbound-gateway as below?

query="SELECT id FROM account where State in ('ca','ma')"
query="SELECT id FROM account where id = 1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that with out-of-the-box Spring Integration JDBC components.

The `query` property is `final` and can't be changed at runtime.

Consider to use `<service-activator>` with `JdbcTemplate.query()` direct usage.